# iOS не подключает стили

Tags: html, css, ios

Стили на сайте подключаются таким способом: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />`

Вроде ничего необычного. Но на `iOS`, а конкретно в Safari эти стили не подключаются. Если все стили перенести в сам файл и прописать через `<style>`, то все работает, а вот через внешний файл - нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Еси кто-то столкнется, отвечу. Проблема оказалась в кэшэ. Safari упорно не хотел его чистить и если обновить второй раз, то стили появлялись, но потом стили стали включаться при первой загрузке. Возможно он доставал страницу без стилей как старый вариант. Теперь все в порядке.